# Tools to operate a mobile using a desktop PC

Tags: mobile, nokia

I have used software named *[my mobiler](http://www.mymobiler.com/)* which displays the screen of any Windows Mobile connected to a desktop PC and allows the user to control the mobile from the desktop.

Are there other similar software available in the market for [S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) or [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) Nokia mobiles.

Comment: Even I am surprised to see my question down voted :(. People can help me to understand why it was down voted !

Comment: Doesn't belong to stack overflow. How is it related to programming?

Comment: It most definitely does belong here - being able to control your actual mobile device when developing beats an emulator any day, in my book.

Comment: It is related to programming indirectly. After development of a app or website for a windows mobile I use that freeware during testing.

Sometimes even during development this happens as it is easy to use and saves time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Mobiler is very cool - like Remote Desktop but for a phone.

The [Nokia PC Connectivity API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html) doesn't *quite* do the same thing, as it provides a set of APIs to let you control the phone and get data from it. Neither do the [Series 40](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html) or [Series 60](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a7149a5-95a5-4726-913a-3c6f21eb65a5/S60-SDK-0616-3.0-mr.html) emulators, as the phone is emulated rather than real.

Given the significant technology differences between S60, S40 and Windows, I'd be surprised to see this change any time soon.

Now, Maemo (as running on the N900) is a different kettle of fish altogether. Quite remarkably [someone has ported VNC](http://maemo.org/downloads/product/OS2006/vnc-server/) there which should do the job just nicely.